# Получить список устройств, подключенных к шине PCI без использования WMI?

Tags: c#, железо

Как получить список устройств, подключенных к шине PCI без использования WMI с помощью языка C#?

Comment: Не думаю, что .NET позволит вам спуститься к железу. Используйте WinAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, прочитав содержимое ветки реестра [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-enum-registry-tree)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pci = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\PCI");
            var keys = pci.GetSubKeyNames();

            foreach (var keyname in keys)
            {
                var subkey = pci.OpenSubKey(keyname);
                var devices = subkey.GetSubKeyNames();

                foreach (var devname in devices)
                {
                    var devkey = subkey.OpenSubKey(devname);
                    object val = devkey.GetValue("FriendlyName","");
                    if (val == null || (string)val == "")
                    {
                        val = devkey.GetValue("DeviceDesc", "");
                        if (val == null) val = "";
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine((string)val);
                    devkey.Close();
                }
                subkey.Close();
            }
            pci.Close();

            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```